# How to check if the following function is periodic or not?

Tags: periodic-functions

I have $f(x)=\sin(x)$ so it has a period of $2\pi$, and I have $g(x)=\sin (\sqrt{2}\,x)$ so it has a period of $\sqrt{2}\pi$. I also know that a function $f(x)$ is periodic if $f(x)=f(x+p)$, now I want $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. How do I check whether $h(x)$ is periodic or not?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{N}(2\pi) \cap \mathbb{N}(\sqrt{2}\pi) = \emptyset$, it's not periodic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: assume that it is periodic, with period $P$. Then $P$ must be an integer multiple of both $\sqrt{2}\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.  The sum might have a period unrelated to the periods of $f$ and $g$, just by accident.